# Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{p}}$ is non-algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

I want to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{p}}$ , where $p$ is a prime number, is a non-algebraic integer. The minimal polynomial of this number in $\textbf Z[x]$ is $f(x) = px^n - 1$ so its corresponding monic polynomial does not have integer coefficients. I need to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible but I have no idea to show it. I tried to use Eisenstein's criterion but I couldn't use it.

Comment: Hint: apply Eisenstein to the reversed polynomial $z^n - p = z^n f(1/z)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I would say that this works as an answer, even more so than a comment, and one I would happily upvote.

Comment: Can we generalize this question i.e. when is $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}}, m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is non-algebraic integer?